# Does git commit store pointer of child too?

Tags: git

I read that git stores pointer to the parent and some other information about committer and message in a commit.

I was curious if it stores pointer to its child when a child is created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not, because there may be many child commits (when branching occurs) and these childs can be different on different repository copies

Comment: Furthermore, adding/changing the child would also change the parent - and its parent etc. This is not desirable.